# Rent motorhome (test-drive for a month) before buying it?

Tags: europe, campers, motor-homes

I'm interested in buying a second-hand motor-home to do tours in Europe

I have no experience whatsoever with this kind of vehicles so I figured the best plan would be to be able to rent the motor-home for about a month before buying it (to test it, and really check if it's my thing). Is this usually accepted by the sellers of this kind of vehicles? How long do you recommend me to test it, one month is fine?

Additionally, if you have any hints about places where this might be cheaper (i.e. the town where there is an autocaravan manufacturer maybe?), please include them.

Comment: So you'd like us to check every town/shop in Europe (30+ countries) for the best price for you??

Comment: haha, what? did I ask for that? no, but maybe there's some guy which knows about these things and knows couple or three places where they are cheap, near his town?

Comment: Europe the continent? the only problem is: [there are 1,000,000 cities](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_cities_are_there_in_Europe#slide=2&article=How_many_cities_are_there_in_Europe).

Comment: yes, that means that my target audience is larger, there are many people that could potentially answer this!

Comment: Recommend you have a read of the [help] on what is deemed too broad, and then consider isolating and making it more specific.

Comment: I recommend that you guys don't feel frustrated when you cannot answer a question; simply leave it there some months, eventually someone will be able to (I'm not in a hurry)

Comment: Yeah there are tons of questions we can't answer, but we're not 'frustated' about it - it's a learning experience.  I'm actually trying to help you here. This site has rules, you're new, so I'm just pointing you to them to explain why your question was closed.  If you don't wish to change it to fit the model of the site, that's cool, but odds are the community will leave it closed then.  Alternatively, hop into the [chat] - there's no structure in there so you might get some more informal advice.

Comment: @MarkMayo modified, good now?

Comment: ping ping ping...

Comment: yeah I was just giving advice from what I could see. You then choose re-open, and it's up to the community to vote to re-open it, not just me.  If the re-open vote fails, it's because people believe it' still not ready/on-topic/specific enough, and may require more editing.

Comment: do they get notified when I edit?